# Fastest C++ XML parsing library

Tags: c++, libraries, xml, parsing, text-processing

I have thousands of .xml files from size 1MB-45MB (no DTDs). I need to parse and further manipulate these XML files before generating separate .xml files with the results of my regex.

What the fastest open-source XML parsing library for C++? Aside from the parsing library, what other approaches can I use to speed up XML parsing?

Comment: This would really depend on what kind of data you want to extract. If you can, you should aim for a streaming approach, that also allows you to quickly skip data you're not interested in (it's one thing to seek the matching closing tag and another one to build up the whole data structure in the memory while doing so).

Comment: How "fast" do you need it? What have you tried that is too slow?

Answer (score 2):

> RapidXml is an attempt to create the fastest XML parser possible,
>   while retaining useability, portability and reasonable W3C
>   compatibility. It is an in-situ parser written in modern C++, with
>   parsing speed approaching that of strlen function executed on the same
>   data.

http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/

Maybe you could start comparing [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) with this one? [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) is known to be really efficient on speed.
RapidXml is used as backend of some boost libraries, mostly Boost.PropertyTree.

Also, I think maybe a more xml-scheme-specific approach could (maybe) be more efficient because of knowledge of the structure of the code. Such claim is just a supposition but if you're interested, [CodeSynthesis provide a C++ code generators](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/) that takes an xsd file as input. The resulting parsing code might be more helpful... if you take time to define your format in an xsd. There are other similar tools available but it's the one I'm using for my last project. Those tools are mostly based on xerces but you can generate code that is independent. No idea about the performance impact.

Comment: Rapidxml is not suitable for stream processing large files as it is a DOM parser. It needs to load the entire file in memory. Expat or libxml2 will work for OP's scenario and those are what he should benchmark for his data.

Answer (score 1):

Is the raw speed of an XML parser or RegEx engine going to make as much of a difference as a faster processor running code that is easy for you to understand & maintain?

From the example you've given I can envisage very big files being processed.  Even so would you not be wiser to try and find a way of breaking up the files and processing them in parallel to increase throughput and leverage multiple cores rather than focusing on relatively small differences in library speed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a specific XML library suited for this task, which threads the XML parsing by default?

Comment: You'll be better off calling the parser in parallel with different files than by trying to parse a single file using multiple threads.

Comment: Okay, well which of the available free, open-source XML libraries is the fastest at parsing?

Comment: Regex for high performance parsing? I'm surprised.